# Calling this and base constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I have a pretty simple and straightforward question.
What is the standardized way, or the right way, of calling another constructor of a class, along with the base constructor of such class?
I understand that the second example does not work. It just seems hackish to be doing it the third way. So what is the way that the people who designed C# expected users to do this?

For example:

```
public class Person
{
    private int _id;

    private string _name;

    public Person()
    {
        _id = 0;
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}

// Example 1
public class Engineer : Person
{
    private int _numOfProblems;

    public Engineer() : base()
    {
        _numOfProblems = 0;
    }

    public Engineer(string name) : this(), base(name)
    {
    }
}

// Example 2
public class Engineer : Person
{
    private int _numOfProblems;

    public Engineer() : base()
    {
        InitializeEngineer();
    }

    public Engineer(string name) : base(name)
    {
        InitializeEngineer();
    }

    private void InitializeEngineer()
    {
        _numOfProblems = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is dna defined?

Comment: Edited, not the point of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you simplify your approach by using an [optional parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)?

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; protected set; }
        public string Name { get; protected set; }
        public Person(string name = "")
        {
            Id = 8;
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public class Engineer : Person
    {
        public int Problems { get; private set; }
        public Engineer(string name = "")
            : base(name)
        {
            Problems = 88;
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class EngineerFixture
    {
        [Test]
        public void Ctor_SetsProperties_AsSpecified()
        {
            var e = new Engineer("bogus");
            Assert.AreEqual("bogus", e.Name);
            Assert.AreEqual(88, e.Problems);
            Assert.AreEqual(8, e.Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the compiler does not recognize a method/constructor with optional parameters as having the same signature as a method without optional parameters, so if you attempt to override a non optional parameter method/constructor it will not work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I've updated my answer with a unit test that shows the Engineer ctor sets the name and number of problems, and chains the name setting to the parent ctor.

Comment: Say you didn't write the person class, and it does not use name as an optional, but instead, a required parameter.
Now in engineer you want to make a new constructor that also takes a name, but instead, as an optional parameter. In this case, the call to base(name) will not rcognize the required base class parameter as having the same signature as the one in engineer.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you mean. Changing to `Person(string name)` doesn't break that code. The ctor signature of the derived class doesn't have to match the base class. Do you have a code example?